# ls command output colors for jar file

Tags: linux, unix, jar, executable-jar

I copied few jar files to a folder. After running ls command, while one jar file seems green, other two files are seen red. According the link below, it means that it is archive file.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-the-terminal

So why one of the jar seems green and the others are red, what could be the problem?

Comment: i see no link here.  I 'd start by looking at the permissions of the files. are they they same ?

Comment: You have right, it was about permissions.